# Why does old content show up on my webpage?

Tags: html, browser-cache

So I've got content at some site (*example.com/stuff.html*), and I upload a new *stuff.html* file.  But when a user goes and looks at the page, they see the old content instead of the new content.  If they refresh the page (typically by pressing F5), the new content shows up.

**How should I mark the new *stuff.html* so it shows up first, instead of a previous version?**

(I imagine this has something to do with the user's browser caching pages, but I'm not too sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parameters to control browser caching that may be specified in `meta` tag. See http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html

However usually it's a web server's responsibility to return new content or appropriate HTTP status code in case content isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are the users behind a proxy that might be caching? Can you use PHP in the pages to send a no-cache header? Although the "right way" would be to send an HTTP header with PHP, if you cannot do that then you might want to try this meta tag:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: @Quentin, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Quentin: That is why I asked if he can use PHP. Editing the .htaccess would help too, of course. But the one tool that he does have is the meta tag, which though not 100% reliable is in fact respected by most common proxies such as squid, as well as all popular web browsers.